# In OpenCL, is it possible to update an allocated memory location on the GPU using a kernel argument?

Tags: opencl, nvidia

I have allocated an OpenCL buffer (finite array) on the GPU memory. Now I want to update a particular index (a memory location) of that array in each kernel execution (there are multiple kernel executions for the same kernel). Can I pass the new value as a kernel parameter and do the update inside the kernel? Once I update the value, in the next kernel invocation, will the update available?

Comment: Can you describe better what exactly you want to do? To me it is not entirely clear what you mean with updating a particular index. Like updating an offset from the global ID to the memory location? Maybe provide some code or pseudocode. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's not 100% clear what you're asking, but:

- Yes, kernels can perform arbitrary writes to memory locations in buffers allocated using `CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY` or `CL_MEM_READ_WRITE`.
- You can enqueue multiple kernel runs which use the same buffer. Buffer contents will be persisted, according to the rules of OpenCL's memory model.
- If any work-items which write or mix reads and writes to the same memory location, could be scheduled to run concurrently, you will need to use some form of synchronisation.

Note that as @SKO points out in their answer, whether multiple kernel enqueueings could be scheduled to run concurrently depends on whether they are submitted to the same queue and whether that queue is in-order or concurrent. *If you enqueue 2 kernel run batches to the same in-order queue, any updates performed to a read-write buffer in the first run will be available in the second run.* (Assuming such updates are well-defined.)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the index(as well as the value) as a kernel argument.
Say, you enqueue kernels in one specific in-order queue, the update should be available at the next kernel execution.

Comment: You can also pass the new value as a kernel argument.